# EXPLAIN in postgresql not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, syntax-error, explain

I have the following SQL code but it's not working, it says syntax error:

```
EXPLAIN
DROP TABLE cool_table
```

Does anyone know why?

I wrote this question because I was taught to always use EXPLAIN before running a query on the database to avoid running a task that's too much for the database processing, no one told me about don't use EXPLAIN before DROP. Then I had this question about why is EXPLAIN not working with the DROP.

Comment: What is there to explain?

Comment: Can't for the life of me think why I'd want drop table explained....

Comment: `DROP TABLE` isn't really something that needs a query plan. It doesn't care what's in the table or how the data is distributed -- it's just going to _drop the table_.

Comment: hey guys, so the idea was to see how expensive the operation is, make sure it won't hurt the speed of the servers

Comment: How often does one drop a table? If you are doing this frequently then there is a design problem

Comment: umm, pretty often actually, since I'm updating the tables...can I avoid it?

Comment: @KevinZhao Yes, normally updating tables doesn't involve dropping them first. I feel a new question coming

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen since I am changing the column names as well, does dropping the old table and creating a new one make sense?

Comment: @KevinZhao No, there is `ALTER TABLE` to rename columns. But if you need to change column names frequently in production, there is a design problem. In development it's a different thing.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen umm, yeah, I am more just doing queries to get some data and answer some questions, not doing production actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not work - DDL statements has no plan - so EXPLAIN has nothing to show.

Comment: that's not exactly true. A `create table .. as select ...` is DDL as well and _does_ have an execution plan.

Comment: But what is CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ? DDL or SELECT?

Comment: Clearly DDL as it creates a new table.

Comment: ok, I this is exception due strange nature of this statement. For me CREATE AS SELECT is two statements in one box - CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO SELECT - but this topis is not too much important

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, you can't put EXPLAIN before a DROP statement in Postgresql...

Use EXPLAIN not with DROP but other statements